# How do you display data from two tables that are connected via an id?

Tags: asp.net

I have two tables with the following:

```
table 1
sid, schedule, stime, splace, stourid

table 2
tourid, tourname
```

I want to display the `table 1` in a GridView, but with field `stourid` I want `tourname` from `table 2` to be displayed instead of `stourid`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `Join` query:

```
SELECT sid, schedule, stime, splace, tourname
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.stourid = table2.tourid
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that stourid above is a pointer into table 2 and maps onto tourid, I would create a view with a join on tourid/stourid and display the view. Something like:

```
CREATE VIEW myView
AS
SELECT sid, schedule, stime, splace, tourname
FROM
[table 1] AS t1 
JOIN [table 2] AS t2
ON t1.stourid = t2.tourid
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute following SQL statement on your data, bind the results to your table and show only the columns you want shown.

```
select * from table1 join table2 on table1.tourid = table2.tourid
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Inner Join...

```
select t1.sid,t1.schedule,t1.stime,t1.splace,t2.tourname from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.tourid = t2.tourid
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT sid, schedule, stime, splace, tourname 
FROM table1 Cross join 
table2